# SSRS - align specific row in two tables

Tags: reporting-services

I'm looking to develop a SSRS report which gets data from two different datasets (unrelated). Then i have two tablix placed horizontally side by side.

The data in each table can vary on rows, and the client wants to align the specific row (which may not be last Row) in both the tables.

Is there a way to achieve this layout just using expressions? I tried to write a custom code to somewhat achieve the behavior but we are deploying this report to D365 online and there the custom code is not supported in sandbox environment.

if someone has any suggestion which gives me an idea on how to achieve such layout,  it would be very much appreciated.

```
   Table A                       Table B
╔═══════╦══════╗             ╔═══════╦══════╗
║ Col1  ║ Col2 ║             ║ Col1  ║ Col2 ║
╠═══════╬══════╣             ╠═══════╬══════╣
║ A1    ║ A    ║             ║ B1    ║ X    ║
╠═══════╬══════╣             ╠═══════╬══════╣
║ A2    ║ B    ║             ║ B2    ║ Y    ║
╠═══════╬══════╣             ╠═══════╬══════╣
║ A3    ║ C    ║             ║       ║      ║
╠═══════╬══════╣             ╠═══════╬══════╣
║ Align ║ ABC  ║             ║ Align ║ XY   ║
╠═══════╬══════╣             ╠═══════╬══════╣
║ A4    ║ A    ║             ║ B3    ║ B    ║
╠═══════╬══════╣             ╠═══════╬══════╣
║ A5    ║ A    ║             ║ B4    ║ B    ║
╚═══════╩══════╝             ╚═══════╩══════╝
```

Comment: How do you know which row(s) to align? Is there only one to align or the top row and another one?

Answer (score 0):

I think you can achieve this by using the `LookupSet` function in SSRS.

Add a couple of columns to the end of Table A and use the LookupSet function to source the rest of the values..

something like this: (assuming your data set for table B is called DatasetTableB

```
=LookupSet(Fields!Col1.Value, Fields!Col1.Value, Fields!Col2.value, "DatasetTableB")
```

You would do the same for the rest of the columns and get the other values.. where Column1 matches, you get the values.. the rest will be blank

Comment: Thanks for the reply. but the to tables are completely unrelated - there is nothing common. maybe my example show values 1,2 which seems that they are related, but that is not the case. i will update the question, but still i dont see any way to achive it even with Lookup.

Comment: OK.. so your original post with output was a bit misleading.. now my answer looks totally irrelevant! You would try placing them in a rectangle etc.. but there is no way to guarantee any sort of alignment